# Eror in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I tried to create a bot in telegram with python, but it doesnt work. My code is below:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
updater = Updater(Token)
def start(bot,update) :
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Hello')
start_command = CommandHandler('start' , start)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_command)
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

And There is a error from error_log decorator:

> No error handlers are registered, logging exception. Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "c:\users\Parsa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py",
> line 442, in process_update
> handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)   File "c:\users\Parsa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\handler.py",
> line 160, in handle_update
> return self.callback(update, context)   File "", line 4, in start
> chat_id = update.message.chat_id AttributeError: `'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'message'`

What should Ido?

Comment: The error message tells you that the `Updater` instance `update`, has no attribute `message`: `update.message` does not exist. According to the tutorial, there's a chat id at `update.effective_chat.id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the definition of start wrong. Try this:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
updater = Updater(Token)
def start(update, _) :
    update.message.reply_text('Hello')
start_command = CommandHandler('start' , start)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_command)
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Comment: Thank you, bot I  have another question. How can find the `chat_id` for another methods?